# Top 100 values in a Dictionary<string, int> - Why is LinQ so much faster than a foreach loop

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I am writing a simple app to parse a huge textfile(60gb) and store all the words and the amount of time it appears in the file. For testing sake I cut the file down to 2gb.

I have the words and the counts in a Dictionary though I'm finding it hard to believe the results I'm seeing.

Total words in the dictionary: 1128495

Code I'm using:

```
sw.Start();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("<html><head></head><body>");
lock (Container.values)
{
    int i = int.Parse(ctx.Request.QueryString["type"]);
    switch (i)
    {
        case 1: //LinQ
            var values = Container.values.OrderByDescending(a => a.Value.Count).Take(100);
            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("{0} - {1}<br />", value.Key, value.Value.Count);
            }
            break;
        case 2: //Foreach
            foreach (var y in Container.values)
            {

            }
            break;
        case 3: //For
            for (int x = 0; x < Container.values.Count; x++)
            {

            }
            break;
    }                
}
sw.Stop();
sb.AppendFormat("<br /><br /> {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
sb.AppendFormat("</body>");
```

Ran it twice, speeds below are in milliseconds:

LinQ: #1: 598, #2 609

Foreach: #1 1000, # 1020

Why is LinQ faster than a foreach? I assume LinQ has to loop through the Dictionary itself so how does it go about that + sorting it all in such a timely manner?

Edit:
After compiling to Release mode the results are as follows:
LinQ: 796(slower?)
foreach: 945

The app is a simple console app, the code is executing in a HttpListener

Edit 2:
I have managed to figure out what the issue was. When I initialized the dictionary I set its capacity to be 89000000(when processing the 60gb file it would throw an OutOfMemory exception otherwise). For some reason this drastically slows the performance of the foreach loop. If I set the capacity to 1128495 the foreach loop executes in 56 milliseconds.

Why is this happening? If I put a counter in the loop it only runs 1128495 times even with a capacity of 89000000.

Comment: I think we need to see the code you're comparing against to say why LINQ is faster.

Comment: Did you run your test as a release build?

Comment: You ought to show us exactly how you declare your container, and exactly what code you put inside the `foreach` and the `for` loops.

Comment: I suspect: bad test. Have you tried it in a flat console exe, compiled in release, run at the console (not the debugger)?

Comment: I have edited the original question to include updated results in release

Comment: 1. You cannot compare algorithm efficiency with a single run in a jit-ted and garbage-collected environment, because there are _lots_ of things going on which skew the results. Try a 1MB file instead of a 2GB file, run your benchmark 1000 times, and average the results. 2. You are still not showing us the code within the `foreach` loop. Do not worry, we won't steal your industrial secrets.

Comment: I looked at the SSCLI source code of the enumerator of the values collection of `Dictionary<T,K>`, and even though it is not written as tightly as the `CopyTo` method of the values collection, it still looks like there is absolutely no reason why it should be so much slower when the dictionary is sparsely populated. Perhaps there is something I am not seeing in the source code, or perhaps the SSCLI source code does not correspond to the code which is actually in use.

Comment: "Why is this happening? If I put a counter in the loop it only runs 1128495 times even with a capacity of 89000000."  I suspect that with more capacity your data is stored sparsely - leading to cache inefficiencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A foreach loop is implemented by the compiler by calling GetEnumerator() and then calling MoveNext and Current repeatedly on the enumerator. LINQ's OrderByDescending normally works exactly the same way, it basically does a foreach to extract all the elements and then it sorts them.

A quick look in ILSpy shows that OrderByDescending puts the container in an internal type called `Buffer<T>`, which has an optimization: in case the container implements `ICollection<T>`, it uses `ICollection<T>.CopyTo` instead of a foreach loop. Usually OrderByDescending would still not be faster than a foreach loop, because after extracting the elements it has to sort them.

Are you leaving out the code in your foreach loop, code that might explain why it's slower? If  you really are using an empty foreach loop, perhaps the explanation is that the `IEnumerator<T>` type (or `GetEnumerator` method) of `Container.values` is slow compared to its `CopyTo` method.

Comment: The foreach loop is indeed just an empty loop. I will look into what you said and see the results.

Comment: +1 for looking up the implementation of OrderByDescending. The `CopyTo` optimization could in fact explain the difference.

Comment: I have updated the question as I have figured out the cause. I assume the CopyTo method will not have the wasted capacity that the initial dictionary I declared had, so this is most likely what caused the performance fluctuation!

Answer (score 0):

Your LINQ version only takes the first 100 elements!

Remove the `.Take(100)` in order to compare!

Comment: It takes 100 elements *after it has sorted the entire container.*

Comment: @MikeNakis I'm not sure if it sorts the entire container. While you need to *read* the whole container to get the first element, you don't need to *sort* the whole container at that time. Not sure if LINQ sorts lazily, but it is possible, and I think some Haskell implementations sort only the part of the sequence you actually iterate.

Comment: Yes, but the foreach loop following the query only operates on the first 100 elements, where as it operates on all the other elements in the other cases (at least, if there is no magic inside the loops). It is difficult to compare, as the implementation of the other cases is not shown.

Comment: As Mike Nakis stated. It is ordering before it takes the 100 elements. I tried removing the Take(100) and just put a check to break out of the foreach loop once it has iterated 100 times. The results were the same

Comment: Yes, but what are the other loops doing? Are they breaking out after 100 times as well? And why are you not ordering in the other cases?